# Increase performance on large dataset with pivot table relationships (Using Laravel)

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, performance, database-design

Looking for advice on whether I can improve my database statements or if I should start caching query results to increase performance.

The schema is set up as a [Many-To-Many Polymorphic](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship. I have a `Videos` table that contains video information, a `Category` table that contains all the categories and, a `Categorizable` table that contains the pivot information.

The ratio between `Videos` and `Categorizable` is around 1:4. (I.e. for every video there's at least 4+ categories).

The results when accessing pivot data with a 40 row limit and *WITHOUT* offset is: **~1.2s+**. 
Adding offset would increase this even more when offset > 50,000 rows.

Although 1.2 seconds seems small, this is only a small portion of the whole data set which ultimately contains around 30 million video records (thus having ~12+ million categorizable records). I fear 1.2s will multiply with every million records.

## Database schema

**Videos table**:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
id     | title                      | author    | views | duration | etc.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      | What's the biggest word?   | Dictonary | 3432  | 600      | ...
2      | Yearly Videos Roundup 2020 | YouTube   | 165   | 945      | ...
3      | Google SEO Help            | Google    | 1401  | 287      | ...
↓      
101234 | How to cook pasta          | YouTube   | 9401  | 87       | ...
```

Indexes:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Table  | Non_unique | Key_name         | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
videos | 0          | PRIMARY          | 1            | id          | A         | 253057      | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL
videos | 1          | idx_videos_views | 1            | views       | A         | 102188      | NULL     | NULL   |YES   | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL
```

**Categorizable table**:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
id      | category_id | cateogrizable_id | categorizable_type
-------------------------------------------------------------
1       | 5           |  1               | 'Video'
2       | 100         |  2               | 'Video'
3       | 31          |  3               | 'Video'
↓
299052  | 65          |  101234          | 'Video'
```

Indexes:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Table          | Non_unique | Key_name             | Seq_in_index | Column_name      | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
categorizables | 0          | PRIMARY              | 1            | id               | A         | 296745      | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL
categorizables | 1          | idx_category_id      | 1            | category_id      | A         | 82          | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL
categorizables | 1          | idx_categorizable_id | 1            | categorizable_id | A         | 104705      | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL
```

**Categories table**:

```
--------------------
id  | name 
--------------------
1   | Education
2   | Health
3   | Entertainment
↓
100 | News
```

Indexes:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Table       | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
categories  |  0         | PRIMARY  |  1           |  id         |  A        |  100        | NULL     | NULL   |      |  BTREE     |         |               |  YES    | NULL
```

## MySQL

Type: InnoDB

**Laravel Query**:

```
Category::where('id', $cat)
  ->with(['videos' => function($query){ 
    return $query->take(40)->orderby('views'); 
   }])
   ->get();
```

**Turns into MySQL query**:

```
SELECT `videos`.`id`, `views` 
FROM `videos` inner join `categorizables` 
ON `videos`.`id` = `categorizables`.`categorizable_id`
WHERE `categorizables`.`category_id` = 1 
ORDER BY `views` desc 
LIMIT 40 offset 0
```

## Performance Results

The following are the performance outputs from MySQL

```
---------------------------------------------------------
Stage                                          | Duration
---------------------------------------------------------
stage/sql/starting                             | 0.000068
stage/sql/Executing hook on transaction begin. | 0.000000
stage/sql/starting                             | 0.000003
stage/sql/checking permissions                 | 0.000001
stage/sql/checking permissions                 | 0.000001
stage/sql/Opening tables                       | 0.000038
stage/sql/init                                 | 0.000003
stage/sql/System lock                          | 0.000005
stage/sql/optimizing                           | 0.000007
stage/sql/statistics                           | 0.005628
stage/sql/preparing                            | 0.000008
stage/sql/Creating tmp table                   | 0.000033
stage/sql/executing                            | 1.273442
stage/sql/end                                  | 0.000001
stage/sql/query end                            | 0.000001
stage/sql/waiting for handler commit           | 0.000008
stage/sql/removing tmp table                   | 0.000003
stage/sql/closing tables                       | 0.000006
stage/sql/freeing items                        | 0.000080
stage/sql/cleaning up                          | 0.000000
```

Specifically:

`stage/sql/executing                            | 1.273442`

**Query Cost**:

```
----------------------------------
Variable_name     | Value
----------------------------------
Last_query_cost   | 107258.575124
```

**EDIT:**

### Explain Query

With sorting:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | select_type | table          | partitions | type   | possible_keys                        | key             | key_len | ref                                     | rows  | filtered | Extra
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | SIMPLE      | categorizables | NULL       | ref    | idx_category_id,idx_categorizable_id | idx_category_id | 4       | const                                   | 51210 | 100.00   | Using temporary; Using filesort
1  | SIMPLE      | videos         | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                              | PRIMARY         | 4       | dev_db.categorizables.categorizable_id  | 1     | 100.00   | Using index
```

Without sorting:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | select_type | table          | partitions | type   | possible_keys                        | key             | key_len | ref   | rows  | filtered | Extra
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | SIMPLE      | videos         | NULL       | index  | NULL                                 | PRIMARY         | 4       | NULL  | 40    | 100.00   | Backward index scan; Using index
```

Comment: So, now we see that sorting slows down the query, we can decompose it to few queries. (try to avoid joins for now). the problem that I see is that the index cardinality for category_id is 82 (too small for you big table)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't leave out the INNER JOIN as that is a big part of the application - being able to sort through videos via categories is essential. I will update the index cardinality to a higher value but this was set via MySQL workbench automatically (Not sure if it's correct). I am having trouble understanding why this would take so long on 300k categorizable rows.

Comment: You can't update it. one hack could help. in case you know that all rows you would get has "views" more thar N, you could try to add it to the query

Comment: with sorting you affect  51210 rows, the goal is to low down this value

Comment: Which table is `views` in??  It makes a big difference.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me walk you through the worst case:

```
SELECT  v.`id`, v.`views`
    FROM  `videos` AS v
    inner join  `categorizables` AS c  ON v.`id` = c.`categorizable_id`
    WHERE  c.`category_id` = 1
    ORDER BY  v.`views` desc
    LIMIT  40 offset 50000
```

The flow goes something like:

1. Look in `categorizables` for all the rows with `category_id = 1`.  This may or may not use an index:  `INDEX(category_id, categorizable_id)` may help.
2. For each of those rows, reach into `videos` to get `views` and `id`.  Assuming that `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, I have no added recommendation.
3. Gather all that stuff into a temporary table.  (Presumably more than 50K rows?)
4. Sort that table.
5. Read through the sorted table, skipping over 50000 rows.
6. Deliver 40 rows and quit.

I hope it is obvious that removing the sort or removing the offset or (etc), will lead to a simplified execution plan, and hence be faster.

You say there is a many-to-many relationship?  Is that `categorizables`?  Does it followed the performance tips here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table ?

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth reply. Yes, `categorizables` is the pivot table. I believe I have it set up similar to the article linked. Yes, removing the sort removes the long execution but if not this way then how would one sort large data sets?

Comment: @l3fty - The large `OFFSET` is also an issue in the sluggishness.

Comment: @l3fty - When an index can be used, the sort can be avoided.  But there are _multiple_ things in the way of that optimization.  For example, moving `category_id` into `videos` would let `INDEX(category_id, views)` avoid the sort.  (But then the huge offset gets in the way.)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) to see how many duplicate queries you are doing.

Next you can eager load the relationship when you fetch the data e.g:

**Index Controller**

```
$videos = Videos::with('categories')->get();
return $videos;
```

You can use also Caching for Laravel e.g:

```
$videos = \Cache::rememberForever('key', function() {
  return Video::with('categories')->get();
});

return $videos;
```

Comment: Appreciate the reply but my call on `Category::with('videos')` is just the inverse of `Videos::with('categories')`. It's a single `INNER JOIN` query. I also plan to use caching if I cannot reduce this query time although with larger datasets I worry even the initial query will be slow.

Comment: you can also do pagination. or see more?